# How to replace a particular comma in a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have quite a big CSV file where lines have varying length:

```
215080,49,3,0.0,22,42,0.0
215082,49,3,0.0,22,43,59.999 
215083,49,3,0.0,22,45,0.0
215085,49,3,0.0,22,46,59.999
215086,49,3,0.0,22,48,0.0
215087,49,3,0.0,22,49,0.001
215088,49,3,0.0,22,49,59.999
215089,49,3,0.0,22,51,0.0
215090,49,3,0.0,22,52,0.001
215688,49,1,59.999,22,49,0.001
215689,49,1,59.999,22,49,59.999
215690,49,1,59.999,22,51,0.0
215691,49,1,59.999,22,52,0.001
216291,49,1,0.001,22,51,0.0
216292,49,1,0.001,22,52,0.001
216293,49,1,0.001,22,52,59.999
```

I would like to replace, for example, only the fourth comma (`,`) in every line with a semicolon (`;`). How can I do this most efficiently?

Comment: The fourth comma only, or the fourth, eighth, 12th, and so on?

Comment: @Warren P Sorry if it is not clear, the fourth coma only as You can see, the fourth coma is separator between coordinates, latitude and longitude

Comment: English tip: "the fourth" is clear. Just the 4th. "Every fourth" means 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('source.csv','rb') as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open('revised.csv','wb') as target:
        wtr= csv.writer( target )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[2], '{0};{1}'.format(r[3],r[4]), r[5], r[6]) )
```

Comment: Thanks for Your solution...although I had to change the last line to:    wtr.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[2], '{0};{1}'.format(r[3],r[4]), r[5], r[6]) )

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this on each line of input.

```
tmp = line.split(',', 4)
newline = '%s;%s' % (','.join(tmp[:4]), tmp[4])
```

Comment: This would work unless it's a true CSV file with things like embedded quotes around fields that contain commas inside the literal string values.  It works for the inputs that the OP specified, for instance.

Comment: @WarrenP: What do you mean by a "true" CSV file? I didn't think that there was a standard. Software that I've seen uses lots of different conventions for trying to have fields with commas in them a "CSV".

Comment: @Charles: There may not be One True CSV, but Python's `csv` module is configurable enough to understand several variations, including Excel's, which I would think is the dominant variant of CSV in the real world.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that you could pass a second parameter to `split`.

Comment: This code more readable and much faster than the `csv` version. If you know that input file doesn't contains extra commas you should go with the `split` version and don't over engineer stuff.

Comment: import csv = over-engineered?  'x'.join( foo ) is more readable? I guess we disagree there.

Comment: solutions that only work in particular cases are not solutions, use the parser and be safe for current and future input.

Comment: @Samus_: Unless you have some knowledge of the spec being used that I don't, I'm not sure how using a different parser is necessarily safer for current and future input.

Comment: first of all, you're not using a parser; now regardless of the different flavors any CSV is allowed to quote each field and within the quoted field there can be commas, that breaks your code. it is also possible to have newlines within fields and backslash-escape literal commas that are not field separators, all those are valid situations that are correctly handles by the csv parser, not in your case.

Comment: @Samus_: I am using a parser, it's a simple two line python parser. Many simple CSV formats provide no provision for quoting; many don't treat a backslash as a special character. If you use a parser that treats a comma in quotes as a single field then it has just as much potential to break a format that doesn't treat quotes specially. Unless you define what CSV format is required, I don't see how using a parser with one particular set of features is any more or less correct than one that has a different set of features.

Comment: no you're not, a parser is a mechanism that interprets some input based on some syntactic rules, you're just splitting on a comma and while that may be considered a simple language is certaily not CSV. the cases you mention are not CSV either, CSV allows any input.

Comment: @Samus_: My code interprets input based on a simple set of syntactic rules so it meets your definition of _parser_. It sounds like you are using CSV to refer to a particular dialect or variant of CSV. If that's the case then my parser won't meet your definition of a CSV parser but it's far from obvious to me that the question asker is using the same definition of CSV as you are. I'm not sure what you mean by "allows any input". Many parsers allow any input, it's how they interpret the input that varies based on the rules being employed.

Comment: no I'm talking about the actual meaning of CSV, you're talking about a particular case of input thus my concern about general usage. nevertheless you're being obstinate about something that is obvious, you'll never learn anything that you don't want to but that doen't make it any less true.

Comment: @Samus_: I'm not trying to be obstinate. So that I can learn, can you tell me what your understanding of "the actual meaning of CSV" is? Personally, I don't think we're using the term to mean the same thing but I'm not sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6114/discussion-between-samus-and-charles-bailey)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
>>> a = '215080,49,3,0.0,22,42,0.0'
>>> b = a.split(',')
>>> ','.join(b[0:3] + [b[3] + ';'  + b[4]] + b[5:])
'215080,49,3,0.0;22,42,0.0'
```